# AsciiDoc syntax highlighting TypeScript JSX (TSX) in PDF

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

I am using AsciiDoc to write a university React & TypeScript course. For the HTML5 backend, I managed to configure the [Prism](https://prismjs.com/) source code highlighter, which is working great.

What is the recommendation to highlight TypeScript JSX (TSX) source code in PDF? As far as I can tell, [rouge](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/issues/516) and [pygments](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/709) don't support this yet.

Comment: The Rouge issue that you linked to was closed because the implementation was added in this PR: https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/pull/669

TSX and Typescript support is listed in the Lexers documentation: https://rouge-ruby.github.io/docs/Rouge/Lexers.html

Rouge would be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I wrongly assumed that rouge was still missing JSX support because even my very basic snippets were not rendered correctly. I've just [filed an issue](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/issues/1517), so we'll see...

Comment: The TSX / TypeScript lexers have been fixed in rouge v3.20.0 – working well now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v3.20.0, [rouge](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/releases/tag/v3.20.0) properly supports TypeScript & TSX